# What does "array_expression" mean in php?

Tags: php, arrays, expression, language-construct

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Trying to better understand the foreach loop. In the documentation above it states "The first form loops over the array given by array_expression."

What in the world is an array_expression?

Comment: `array_expression` is the _possible variable_ name (`foreach (array_expression as $value)`) and it can also be an actual array

Comment: An `array_expression` is simply a PHP Array or Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *array_expression* is any [expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) that results in an array.  So these are expressions that are not arrays themselves but result in an array when evaluated:

```
foreach(range(1, 5) as $val){}
```

Or:

```
foreach($array = range(1, 5) as $val){}
```

Or:

```
class Test {
    public static function do_it() {
        return range(1, 5);
    }
}

foreach(Test::do_it() as $val){}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php)'s descriptionpage

> Expressions are the most important building blocks of PHP. In PHP, almost anything you write is an expression. The simplest yet most accurate way to define an expression is "anything that has a value".

So, this means `array_expression` is just a <del>dumb</del> dummy text to let you know that the foreach takes array function.

In this case,

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
   var_dump($value);
}
```

would result:

```
int(1) int(2) int(3)
```

Comment: I would also show example with `foreach (array(1,2,3) as &$value) {` (or similar style) to show the differences to use an array in  the loop

Comment: But how can an array ever be an expression?

Comment: I struggled over the same thing when I started to learn PHP. Here is a page dedicated entirely to what an expression means [Expressions are the most important building block....](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php)